Digital Nomad Visa in South Korea and difference with a normal working Visa
I've just learnt about the Digital Nomad Visa and I was checking if South Korea has it.
Apparently is the F-1-D visa.
I wonder if there's any difference with a normal working visa (from what I can read it is not allowed, obviously, to have a job in korea).
But when it comes to the rest (i.e. living in korea) does this visa have any restriction?
I can see the alien registration card would still be given, so I would assume there would be no difference at all but maybe I am wrong?
Would be nice to know if someone has experience. If it helps I am an Italian citizen settled in UK.

Why is this question tagged "united-kingdom" ?

Because I live there
